# Does Protege upload my ontology to semanticweb.org?

Tags: ontology, protege

I have created a new ontology in Protege. The IRI is something like this

```
http://www.semanticweb.org/Computer1/ontologies/2016/8/untitled-ontology-10
```

Why the naming is like a URL? Does that mean my ontology is loaded to semanticweb.org? My concern is the privacy of my data.

I noticed that I can change the IRI to a local address in my machine but still I want to know is there any option in protege that may upload my data somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

No, the IRI is simply /looking/ like a URL. Your data will not be published anywhere unless you do so yourself.